# How to search file based on DAY of week

Tags: find, timestamps

Actually I need to search for files and folder that were created in 2012 on Friday of every month.

I did some attempts using the `find` command but it didn't work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The simplest way with `find` is:

```
find / -daystart -mtime +41 -mtime -408 \
  -printf "%M %n %u %g %10s %TY-%Tm-%Td %Ta %TH:%TM:%TS %h/%f\n" |
awk '($7=="Fri"){print}'
```

Adjust the `-printf` as required, I've made it look close to `ls -l` here.
`%T` (and `%A` `%C`) let you use `strftime()` formatting for timestamps, `%Ta` being the day of the week. (You may need to adjust the day ranges 41 - 408, but that's really just an optimisation, you can just `grep 2012`, or adjust `-printf` to make it easier to grep.)

**Edit:** a more robust version, with some slight loss of clarity:

```
find / -daystart -mtime +41 -mtime -408 \
   -printf "%M %n %u %g %10s %TY-%Tm-%Td %Ta %TH:%TM:%TS\0%h/%f\0\0" |
gawk 'BEGIN{RS="\0\0"; FS="[\0]"} ($1~/ Fri /) { printf $2 "\0"}' | 
xargs -0 -n 1 -i ls -l "{}"
```

This emulates `-print0`, but each line has two `\0` delimited fields, the filename being the second.
Replace `ls -l "{}"` at the end with whatever you need to do to the file(s). I'm explicitly using `gawk`, other awks do not take so kindly to \0 bytes in `RS`/`FS` (updated to handle newlines in file names too).

Also, as suggested by *mreithub* you can use `%Tu` as well as, or instead of `%Ta` for a numbered weekday, a language independent option.

Comment: Note that something like this will also show files with names containing `Fri`, even if they were never touched on a Friday. I guess you could work around that with a separator, splitting and checking each part. Still, it's a decent approximation using commonly available tools in a semi-readable manner, so +1.

Comment: So, to simplify this, I'd use:
`find /mnt/music/Datenbank -mtime +41 -mtime -408 -printf "%Ta %p\n"|grep ^Fri|sed 's/^Fri //'`. You might need to prepend a LC_ALL=C to make sure the week day is english

Comment: I like it even better now, but can't upvote twice unfortunately `:)` @mreithub's solution in comment is good too.

Comment: I'll upvote it for u @MichaelKjörling ;)

Comment: also note you could use `... -printf %Tu %p\n"|grep ^5|sed 's/^5 //' to make it language-independent (but a little less readable...

Comment: Awesome tip great job. And to make sure that this file is really created on Fri of some month I manually checked in calendar. Thanks All

Comment: I was confused thinking this was modifying or acting on the `ls` command output somehow. It's just reproducing the look: `%M` prints the permissions of the file `find` found, `%f` prints the filename at the end.

Answer (score 0):

With `gnu` tools:

```
find . -exec bash -c '[[ $(date -r "$0" +%u%Y) = "52012" ]]' {} \; -print
```

the files/directories names are `-print`ed only if the previous `-exec` returned *true*, that is if the `mtime` as reported by `date -r` in the specified format (`%u%Y`) is `52012`

Or, if you prefer a `zsh`-only solution (it's quite similar, the `e`-string selects only those files/directories for which the expression inside the quotes returns *true*):

```
zmodload zsh/stat
print -rl -- **/*(De_'[[ $(zstat -F "%u%Y" +mtime -- $REPLY) = "52012" ]]'_)
```